# Google Sign-in not working in incognito mode

Tags: javascript, angular, google-signin

I have used Google sign-in my angular 9 project. I am using google sign-in js API.
It's giving error **Cookies are not enabled in current environment** in google chrome incognito mode, although it's working fine in normal google chrome tab. below is the error details.

```
details: "Cookies are not enabled in current environment."
error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed"
```

Understand that in incognito mode by default third party cookies are disabled but what is the solution for this? I found other sites that are using google sign-in is perfectly working in google chrome incognito mode.

Comment: I am experiencing this very same issue, currently. I've found that, for example, the NYTimes Google login works just fine in an incognito tab. I've had a look at its innards and observed that it's building its buttons quite a bit different from how I build them. Whereas I use gapi (load, init, attachClickHandler), the NYTimes constructs its own auth-URL and puts it on the button. I've experimented with setting cookie_policy to 'none', but it didn't help. Don't think it's ever gonna work incognito, unless you do it NYTimes style. I'll leave it to you to reverse engineer their source.

Answer (score 14):

Angular is just javascript in a browser. So a user loading an angular app is being served a bunch of javascript from your server. If that server handles authentication with google-api, then your user only interacts with your server (albeit with a redirect to sign into google).

This authentication flow doesn't require 3rd party cookies.

**However!** If your authentication is handled directly in the user's browser, then your app will not work if 3rd party cookies are disabled (as they are in incognito mode).

For example, I have an angular app that I serve via Github pages. Github serves the app but then doesn't do anything else. Since I need to create a document in the user's GDrive, I authenticate and access their resources all from within a javascript client. For that to work securely, users of my ap must allow 3rd party cookies. There isn't really a way around that.

If I had a backend for my app, then the user could give my server permission to access their google drive and no 3rd party cookies would be required. At that point, it's not the frontend javascript client (angular app) that is accessing the user's GDrive, but instead my server.

Using a backend allows for a different and generally more secure authentication flow. To a user, however, the user experience is the same. This is why in some situations the user must allow 3rd party cookies and in others, they do not.

In general, you can secure a server much better than you can trust a user's system/browser to be secure. If security is a concern, you really should be making API calls from a server rather than from within a browser. Doing so should also fix your problem.

Comment: I assume this takes a token sent by a user for it to access their data from GDrive? Is there a way I can have my server authenticate (a service account) then access a google drive photo that is private? By making a get request to that link?

Comment: @HassanRaza - The idea is that the user chooses which permissions they give your app. So unless they've given you access to the private photo, you will be barred from even knowing whether such a file exists.

Answer (score 6):

You're probably using `'ux_mode': 'redirect'` which involves iframes and cookies.

Try using `popup` mode.

PS. You mention "Other sites perfectly working" - they are probably using oAuth2 authentication flow server-side, which is based on redirects.

PPS. More info https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/troubleshooting see "Known issues"

Comment: Nope, with popup mode it's the same behavior

Comment: That's because it defaults to 'popup'.

Answer (score 4):

Easy solution could be turning of `Block third-party cookies`.
go to your first page of incognito, you can see in the bottom `Block third-party cookies` turn that of.

this solution works at least for me.

Comment: This does not fix the problem in the site, it just makes it work on OP's computer. It would still be broken for everyone else.

Comment: This fixes the problem of getting chrome plugins to work in incognito mode when they require cookies

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is struggling with google login (specifically getting access token) in incognito mode, reference following example implementation in Next.js

```
export default function useGoogleLogin() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const matches = window.location.hash.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/);
    if (!matches) {
      return;
    }

    console.log('Access token', matches[1])
  }, []);

  const handleLogin = () => window.location.replace(getAuthUri());

  return { handleLogin };
}
```

And here's a implementation of getAuthUri

```
export default function getAuthUri() {
  let base = window.location.href,
    state = "";
  let i = base.indexOf("#");
  if (i > -1) {
    state = base.substring(i);
    base = base.substring(0, i);
  }
  return (
    "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth" +
    "?client_id=" +
    encodeURIComponent(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID) +
    "&redirect_uri=" +
    encodeURIComponent(base) +
    "&state=" +
    encodeURIComponent(btoa(state)) +
    "&response_type=" +
    encodeURIComponent("token") +
    "&scope=" +
    encodeURIComponent("profile") +
    "&include_granted_scopes=" +
    encodeURIComponent("true")
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Session Management is required to be done if we want to sustain any data in incognito mode.

Spring Session provides an API and implementations for managing a user’s session information while also making it trivial to support clustered sessions without being tied to an application container-specific solution. It also provides transparent integration with:

HttpSession: Allows replacing the HttpSession in an application container-neutral way, with support for providing session IDs in headers to work with RESTful APIs.

WebSocket: Provides the ability to keep the HttpSession alive when receiving WebSocket messages

WebSession: Allows replacing the Spring WebFlux’s WebSession in an application container-neutral way.